# Dense free subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups, free-groups, p-groups

Let $F$ be a free pro-$p$ group (for a prime number $p$) on a finite set $X$, $\Phi$ the abstract subgroup generated by $X$, $\{1\} \neq N \lhd_c F$. Is it possible that $\Phi \cap N = \{1\}$?

Comment: For $\#(X)\ge 2$, yes, it's an exercise: pick any pro-$p$-group $G$ with a dense free subgroup $\Phi$ (e.g. a congruence subgroup in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$), then if $N$ is the kernel of the natural map $F\to G$, then $N\cap\Phi=\{1\}$.

Comment: @YCor: In your example, the group $\Phi$ is finitely generated, right?

Comment: $\Phi$ is free over $X$ which is any finite set of cardinal $\ge 2$.

Comment: @YCor: Do you think that there is a chance to find another basis $Y$ for $F$ such that the abstract subgroup it generates intersects $N$ nontrivially?

Comment: I don't know, this sounds not obvious. I don't even know if there is any element in $F$ not belonging to the abstract subgroup generated by any basis of $F$, maybe you know one?

Comment: @YCor : I do not know of such an element, and I suspect that there might not be such (very curious to find one). On the other hand, I know of such elements if $F$ is a free profinite group.

Comment: Yes: for instance any element in the kernel of the canonical morphism from the free profinite group over $X$ to the free pro-$p$-group over $X$.